# How can I make a white screen of death less ugly

Tags: 8, wsod

A project I'm working on requires custom modules, and I'll be the last person to claim that I am perfect. I've gone through and removed as many possible php errors and causes for WSODs that I can think of, and I haven't had any recently. In the case that an error does happen with my code it will affect a single page load, it won't totally take the site down. The last thing I want is a user seeing a clearly broken page with text saying "your website is broken".

Is there a way I can display/redirect to a general (and pretty) "There was a problem completing your request, please contact site administrators" error page?

Comment: Use try / catch statements on the offending code to recover as gracefully as possible. But no, in the event of a 500 error, this is usually done at the server level (maintenance page) because the application cannot complete the request.

Comment: you could also make use of an eventlistener and listen for `'onKernelException'` and check the response-code